# How to export a grid layer to google earth as boxes

Tags: export, kml, google-earth, vector-grid, mmqgis

I have a grid made using MMQGIS which I want to label box-wise (custom and non-consecutively) and export to kml to use in Google Earth using the same labelled boxes. If I export kml normally I get each side of the box separately which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to convert your grid to polygons - one polygon for each "box" that you want, before exporting to KML.